# grep: Invalid back reference when trying to find palindrome

Tags: regex, bash, sh, palindrome

I have a bash script where I'm trying to recognize palindromes from a given `words.txt` file, I think I'm on the right track using grep but I'm not sure. I have to use only character classes such as `\w` or `[:alpha:]` to refer to letters in the alphabet but whenever I try to execute the program I'm getting an error:

> grep: Invalid back reference.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on how to fix this problem? Thanks!

EDIT:
my new code but now regex 3 (almost works but gives me an extra word its not supposed to) and 5 (isn't doing anything) aren't doing what they are supposed to, any help please?

```
#!/bin/bash

src_file="words.txt"

regex1='^(.)(.).\2\1'
regex2='^(.)(.)(.)\3\2\1'
regex3='^(.)(.)(.).\3\2\1'
regex4='(.)\1+'
regex5='^(.)\1{2}'

echo 'These are the five letter palindromes:'
egrep $regex1 $src_file

echo ' '
echo 'These are the six letter palindromes:'
egrep $regex2 $src_file

echo ' '
echo 'These are the seven letter palindromes:'
egrep $regex3 $src_file

echo ' '
echo 'These are the words that contain at least two instances of the same doubled characters (such as willfully (contains ll twice) and riffraff (contains ff twice)):'
egrep $regex4 $src_file

echo ' '
echo 'These are the words that contain at least three instances of doubled characters (such as bookkeeper  (oo, kk, and ee) and keenness (ee, nn, and ss):'
egrep $regex5 $src_file
```

Comment: Replace `egrep` with `grep` or remove all backslashes before brackets.

Comment: `egrep $regex3 $src_file` where `$regex3` is essentially undefined might very well generate that error message. Good luck.

Comment: @Cyrus cheers that worked, thank you! However, now I'm realizing that my regex's are wrong... I totally thought I had the 6 letter palindromes with (.)(.)(.)\3\2\1 but that isn't working and its spitting out palindromes with more than 6 letters, any idea as to why?

Comment: `regex2='^\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\3\2\1$'`?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Regarding `regex3`, what is the *extra word* which is not supposed to?  It is essentially same as `regex1`.

Comment: Putting the regexes in variables doesn't really buy you anything, and you really should [quote your variables](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642) if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `regex3` looks almost ok, but possible overmatch will be the case with
words such as `wow wow` or `revivers`. Then please try:

```
regex3='^(.)(.)(.)\w\3\2\1$'
```

To be strict, it will be safer to replace all dots with `\w` as:

```
regex3='^(\w)(\w)(\w)\w\3\2\1$'
```

Needless to say the anchor `$` is required for `regex1` and `regex2`.

As of `regex4`, it should be:

```
regex4='(\w)\1.*\1\1'
```

or

```
regex4='((\w)\2).*\1'
```

to match with `willfully` and `riffraff`.

and `regex5` should be:

```
regex5='(\w)\1.*(\w)\2.*(\w)\3'
```

to match with `bookkeeper` and `keenness`.

Note that the character class `\w` is equivalent to  `[[:alnum:]]`.
If you want to limit the matching only to alphabets, please replace `\w`
with `[[:alpha:]]`.

BTW you can also check if a variable `$str` is a palindrome with:

```
[[ $str = $(rev <<< "$str") ]] && echo "$str is a palindrome"
```

as an alternative.

Hope this helps.